# Bitwise OR along one axis of a NumPy array

Tags: numpy

For a given NumPy array, it is easy to perform a "normal" sum along one dimension. For example:

```
X = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 3]])
X.sum(0)
    =array([1, 2, 5])
X.sum(1)
    =array([1, 4, 3])
```

Instead, is there an "efficient" way of computing the bitwise OR along one dimension of an array similarly? Something like the following, except without requiring for-loops or nested function calls.

Example: bitwise OR along zeroeth dimension as I currently am doing it:

```
np.bitwise_or(np.bitwise_or(X[:,0],X[:,1]),X[:,2])
    =array([1, 2, 3])
```

What I would like:

```
X.bitwise_sum(0)
    =array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
numpy.bitwise_or.reduce(X, axis=whichever_one_you_wanted)
```

Use the [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) method of the `numpy.bitwise_or` ufunc.