# How to perform bitwise and operation on matrices of a tensor in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I have the following numpy tensor:

```
M = np.zeros((a,b,c), dtype=bool)
```

I wish to perform a bitwise and on all `a` matrices of dimension `b,c`
to give a final matrix of dimensions `b,c`. I do not know how to achieve this
efficiently. Something like

`np.apply_along_axis(func1d=np.bitwise_and, axis=0, arr=M)`
but I get the error message: `ValueError: invalid number of arguments`
and I am unclear why.

UPDATE: This works, but is there a more (time) efficient way?

```
v = np.ones((b,c),dtype=bool)
for i in range(0, a):
  v = v & M[i]
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40941207/8998310) answers your question.

Comment: What is `a`? Is it an integer? Or an array? How come it works both in `range(0,a)` and `a[I]`?

Comment: Looks like `a` is an integer. I suspect `a[i]` should be `M[i]`

Comment: If that's the case, I think Jose is indeed right , use smth like `np.bitwise_and.reduce(v)`

Comment: Yes, sorry typo. Should've been `M[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) for this:

```py
>> M = np.zeros((8,9,10), dtype=np.bool)
>> M.all(0).shape
(9, 10)
```